# Excel VBA temporarily save value

Tags: excel, vba, save, saving-data

I'm writing a little program which selects an Employee out of a pool of names with a seed. The image of the selected employee shows up in a userframe.

I'd like the program to keep the selected a employee's name for the whole day. In this case, even if I restart the program 2 hours later, the selected employee keeps logged in. On the next day the program selects a new employee with the seed, who also stays selected the whole day.

My question is: how would I save the selected employee for the Whole day?

Example:

- Start program -> start seed -> selected employee: Thomas -> show Thomas' image

2 hours later:

- Start program -> selected employee: Thomas -> still shows Thomas' image

next day:

- Start program -> start seed -> selected employee: Christoph -> show Christoph's image

If you have any ideas or helpful answers I'd be very thankful!

Comment: Have your seed be based off date.

Comment: that sounds like an interesting idea! I'll try that. Thank you

Comment: @josephc I did try to find a way to base my seed on the date but didn't find a solution. The seed works with a simple combination of randomize- and rnd-function. You see any chance?

Comment: Post what you've tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do it, i just save the date and the Value of the day in a certain cell on my sheet. This is how my code looks like:

If MainSheet.Cells(1, 1) = Date Then
    selectedemployee = MainSheet.Cells(1, 2)
Else
    ceed procedure

```
MainSheet.Cells(1,1) = Date    'saves the date in Sheet
MainSheet.Cells(1,2) = selectedemployee    'saves todayValue in Sheet
```

End If